# Typescript Code is not returning any output, but is running

Tags: javascript, typescript, uipath

I am trying to get a string with a number where, if there is a match between the former and later number add it to a sum total, so 55412 will be 5 and 112332 will be 1 + 3 so 4. This is coded in typescript, the problem is my code doesn't output anything.

```
function uipath(e, arg)
{
  let stringToInt = new StringToInt("5514133");
  stringToInt.charCompareAndSum();
  stringToInt.stringSplit();
  alert (stringToInt.getSumList.toString);
}

class StringToInt
{
  private argumentString : string ;
  private numberArr : Array<string>;
  private sumList : number;

  constructor( arg: string)
  {
    this.argumentString = arg ;
  }

  stringSplit()
  {
    this.numberArr = this.argumentString.split(/(?=.)/u);
  }

  charCompareAndSum()
  {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.numberArr.length -1; i++ )
    {
      if (this.numberArr[i] == this.numberArr[i+1])
      {
        this.sumList = this.sumList + +this.numberArr[i];
      }
    }    
  }

  get getSumList():number
  {
    return this.sumList;
  }
}
```

The output should be 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you need to call your functions:

```
stringToInt.getSumList.toString
```

Should be

```
stringToInt.getSumList().toString()
```

I'm guessing this prints nothing because

```
stringToInt.getSumList
```

Evaluates to the `getSumList` function itself, then

```
getSumList.toString
```

Evaluates to `undefined` since the function doesn't have a `toString` property.